# Programmatically accessing field values for a file in a custom form

Tags: entities

I have the `kint()` output below.

[image]

How do I get the values for the *destination* index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the code below and it works.

$destination = $file[0]->toArray()['uri'][0]['value'];

Answer (score 0):

Since the `values` array is a protected value, you can only access its value with a method (e.g. a magic method).

The `File` class extends [`ContentEntityBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/class/ContentEntityBase/8.4.x), from which it gets the `values` property and the magic method that allows to access it. Supposing that `$file` is the variable containing an `\Drupal\file\Entity\File` object, you just need the following code.

```
$destination = $file['destination'];
```

#### Longer Explanation

The method that allows to access the content of the `values` array is [`ContentEntityBase::__get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3A__get/8.4.x) (a magic method) that allows to access the value of an object as it would be an array. `ContentEntityBase::__get()` checks also the content of the `values` array; in fact it contains the following code.

```
  // Else directly read/write plain values. That way, non-field entity
  // properties can always be accessed directly.
  if (!isset($this->values[$name])) {
    $this->values[$name] = NULL;
  }
  return $this->values[$name];
```

So, using `$file['destination']`, that method would return you the value of `$file->values['destination']` you cannot directly access.

Comment: I have $file = file_save_upload('csv_upload', $validators) & $destination = $file['destination']. kint($destination) is NULL. I have also tried $destination = $file['values']['destination'] which is also NULL. Am I missing something?